# ksoap2 exception handling in android

Tags: android, exception, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I'm getting exception in the following code

```
                package com.dipl.smpm.smpm;

 import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
 import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
 import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
 import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
 import org.ksoap2.transport.AndroidHttpTransport;
 import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransport;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;
public class ConnectHttp extends Activity {
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/loginDetails";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "loginDetails";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "http://localhost:88/EmpService.asmx";
    TextView tv;
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView11);
    SoapObject sobj_requestLogin=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    sobj_requestLogin.addProperty("username", "a");
    sobj_requestLogin.addProperty("password", "a");
    SoapSerializationEnvelope spenve_Login = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    spenve_Login.dotNet=true;
    spenve_Login.setOutputSoapObject(sobj_requestLogin);

    AndroidHttpTransport htrans_login= new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

    try{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        htrans_login.call(SOAP_ACTION,spenve_Login);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        SoapPrimitive spprim_login=(SoapPrimitive)spenve_Login.getResponse();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        tv.setText("result: "+spprim_login+" ");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
 }
```

i'm getting a toast '1' sucessfully but its going to 'exception' toast immediately before toast '2' comes. help me what is my mistake? also i'm using 2.3 ksoap2 2.3 jar as user defined lib.

Comment: post your log cat please.

Comment: no error in logcat.... if its necessary i'll upload

Comment: but its going to 'exception'?? what exception are you getting?

Comment: its xml parser exception, Soap Fault Exception and IOException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have just changed localhost in the URL to the ip of the local system. 
it is solved. thanks to @NIRMAL

Answer (score 1):

Use Like this.

```
   final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/loginDetails";
    final String METHOD_NAME = "loginDetails";
    final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    final String URL = "http://localhost:88/EmpService.asmx";


    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("username", "a");
    request.addProperty("password", "b");
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                          envelope.dotNet = true;
                      envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
          ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
          final SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                String str = response.toString();          
        }
     catch (Exception e) 
     {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Add this line in your manifest.xml:

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
> ```

Comment: then, the problem might be your parameter username and password. is that the same parameter have you used in your webservice?

Comment: yes the same. should i include the response param name also??? i don't know how in actual the web service is written. one of my friend helped me in it

Comment: post your webservice here?

Comment: sorry i can't disclose it. :( . i have serious warning from the developer not to do so. its priorly IOException. What might be ruined???

Comment: See my edited answer have you added that in your manifest.xml?